# I recently installed Ubuntu to a USB drive and I can't get back to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, usb

Just rewriting this post so it's more clear.

I'm unable to get back to Windows after I burned Ubuntu to my USB Drive after using a program called "Rufus".

Now, when I attempt to boot Windows, even after I took out my USB Drive, it will still boot to Ubuntu.

I'm not sure about what to do to get back to Windows, and I'm worried because I had important photos and videos there as well.

When I attempt to get back to it, it says "No partitions detected", so this may be the problem.

EDIT #2 : The problem may be that I didn't select the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option, but rather the second one (I forget the name...).

Comment: please describe what you have done and what you do when you try to start Win

Comment: Also, I stupidly never remembered to make a backup of said photos/videos, which is even more worrying. I seriously don't want this to screw over my computer...

Comment: @cmak.fr I thought it would only save to my USB drive. But now, when I boot, it goes to Ubuntu. Also, I used "rufus" to save Ubuntu to my USB drive and installed it. That's pretty much it.

Comment: It looks like you installed Ubuntu not to a USB drive but to your HDD and wiped your Windows installation.

Comment: @Pilot6 Shoot... What can I do to get it back, then?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what would actually happen if you did it, but maybe in rufus you installed onto the c drive.  If this is the case it would start at the screnn asking if you want to install or try I think.

Comment: OK, well, this is apparently what I did. Is there no way to get back to Windows after this? If so, would my files be alright? (Also, on Rufus, I clearly made it so it went onto my USB, which is 16GB in size.)

Comment: Your files are not alright. Most of them can be recovered with no guarantee.

Comment: Rufus developer here. Nope, as opposed to other applications Rufus will __NEVER__ list the `C:` drive as a selectable target. There's a whole sway of code ensuring that you can not format an internal drive such as `C:` in Rufus. Most likely OP booted from the USB then selected the _Install Ubuntu_ option, and used their Windows drive as the target then (which the Ubuntu installer will let you do).